# Access Django simple history logs outside from admin?

Tags: django, logging, django-simple-history

I am using [**Django simple history**](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in my project to store LogEntry. I have API build using **Django rest framework** (DRF) and front-end using Angularjs.
The LogEntry history for the objects is saved without any problems as shown below in the picture!

[image]

**models.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords


class Person(models.Model):

    """ Person model"""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    workphone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, default='')
    avatar = models.FileField(upload_to="", blank=True, default='')
    createdtstamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords(inherit=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.first_name
```

I can access object history from django admin without any problems. But, 
**how can I access LogEntry history outside from Django admin? I want to Serialize logs queryset and return response in json format.**

**What I know and done so far?**

```
from person.models import Person
from datetime import datetime

>>> person = Person.objects.all()
>>> person.history.all()
```

Comment: This sounds like a code this for me question ATM. Please do add your best effort

Comment: I revised and tried my best @e4c5!

Answer (score 3):

you can retrieve the data by using a ListView.

**Assuming your django-simple-history is correctly configured, follow the procedures below:**

Model **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

View **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Poll

# Create your views here.

class PollHistoryView(ListView):
    template_name = "pool_history_list.html"
    def get_queryset(self):
        history = Poll.history.all()
        return history
```

Template **pool_history_list.html**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>History Date/Time</th>
            <th>History Action</th>
            <th>History User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for t in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ t.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ t.question }}</td>
            <td>{{ t.history_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ t.get_history_type_display }}</td>
            <td>{{ t.history_user }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

make your own historyserializer like this...

```
class HistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Person
```

and then in your views...

```
class HistoryViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HistorySerializer

    @list_route(methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def history(self,request):
        var=Person.history.all()
        serialized_data=HistorySerializer(var,many=True)
        return Response(serialized_data.data)
```

Comment: Sorry! The Answer is correct. I press the wrong button for the downvote.